# How to hide specific div when clicked outside the element having same class in multiple div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code snippet where I want to hide specific `div` having same class name. I have multiple divs having same class name and event need to be triggered outside the `actionLinks` class. But I am little bit confused how to do this. can you guide me?

```js
$(document).on("click", ".actionLinks", function() {
  $('.mainAction').hide();
  $(this).prev('.mainAction').show();
});

$(document).not(".actionLinks").on("click", function() {
  $('.mainAction').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainAction" style="display: none;">
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#">Link one</a>
</div>
<div class="mainAction" style="display: none;">
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#">Link two</a>
</div>
<div class="mainAction" style="display: none;">
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#">Link three</a>
</div>
<div class="mainAction" style="display: none;">
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#">Link four</a>
</div>
<div class="mainAction" style="display: none;">
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#">Link five</a>
</div>
<div class="mainAction" style="display: none;">
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#">Link six</a>
</div>
<div class="mainAction" style="display: none;">
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#">Link seven</a>
</div>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try **`event.target`**. Check below snippet

```js
$(document).on("click", "body", function(event) {
  if (!$('.actionLinks a').is(event.target) && $('.actionLinks a').has(event.target).length === 0) {
    $('.mainAction').hide();
    $(event.target).show().closest('.mainAction').show();
  } else {
    $('.mainAction').hide();
    $(event.target).closest('.actionLinks').prev('.mainAction').show();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

.mainAction {
  display: none;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.mainAction a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.actionLinks a {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mainAction">
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#">Link one</a>
</div>
<div class="mainAction">
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#">Link two</a>
</div>
<div class="mainAction">
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#">Link three</a>
</div>
<div class="mainAction">
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#">Link four</a>
</div>
<div class="mainAction">
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#">Link five</a>
</div>
<div class="mainAction">
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#">Link six</a>
</div>
<div class="mainAction">
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#">Link seven</a>
</div>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$(document).not(".actionLinks").on(...)`, you can do the same action in following way,

```
$(':not(div.actionLinks)').click(function(){
    $('div.mainAction').hide();
});
```

Comment: It will solve the problem of OP, but this selector is really bad practise. This is a very expensive selector. Even if the div.mainAction isn't visible click events will be catched.

Comment: I have created a plunker example, https://plnkr.co/edit/vzFFdyJXReKeZ9mL6BPK?p=preview

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst do you have any good solution for above mentioned problem?

Answer (score 0):

Append [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event to body to catch every [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event and check whether it contains your class.

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if(!e.target.classList.contains("mainAction")) {
        hideElem(openedMainActionElement);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this without javascript by linking to id's and using the `:target` selector. This has the advantage of having a semantic link between the `a` tag and the target `div`

```css
.mainAction {
  display: none;
}

.mainAction:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="actions1" class="mainAction">
  <h3>Actions 1</h3>
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#actions1">Link one</a>
</div>
<div id="actions2" class="mainAction">
  <h3>Actions 2</h3>
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#actions2">Link two</a>
</div>
<div id="actions3" class="mainAction">
  <h3>Actions 3</h3>
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#actions3">Link three</a>
</div>
<div id="actions4" class="mainAction">
  <h3>Actions 4</h3>
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#actions4">Link four</a>
</div>
<div id="actions5" class="mainAction">
  <h3>Actions 5</h3>
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#actions5">Link five</a>
</div>
<div id="actions6" class="mainAction">
  <h3>Actions 6</h3>
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#actions6">Link six</a>
</div>
<div id="actions7" class="mainAction">
  <h3>Actions 7</h3>
  <a href="#">Action 1</a>
  <a href="#">Action 2</a>
  <a href="#">Action 3</a>
</div>
<div class="actionLinks">
  <a href="#actions7">Link seven</a>
</div>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```